# Newtonsoft.Json Serializer settings not working on aspnet core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net

I have the below configuration in my ASP.NET Core app

```
services
    .AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add<CacheActionFilter>();
        options.Filters.Add<OutputModelActionFilter>();
    })
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(setupAction =>
    {
        setupAction.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
        {
            NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
        };
        // use the line below for CamelCase
        // setupAction.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        setupAction.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
        setupAction.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        setupAction.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    });
```

The only Serializer setting that is having any effect is the `ReferenceLoopHandling` setting.  Other settings, like the `StringEnumConverter` seem to be ignored.  The only way I can get enums to be converted to their string values is to add the `JsonConverter` attribute on my class property.

Am I missing something?  Everything on the internet suggests this should work.

Currently I'm using net 3.1 but I also tried upgrading to net 6.0 and I get the same result.

**EDIT FOR CLARITY**
The problem is with JSON being generated as output from my api methods.  Not manually calling Json.Serialize.

Comment: And just to clarify, we're talking about models posted as input to your endpoints, or being returned from your endpoints? Right? Not manual `JsonConvert.Serialize` calls?

Comment: Sorry, yes it's models being returned from my endpoints.  Not manually calling JsonConvert.Serialize.  I will update.

Comment: What do the `Filters` do? Have you tried removing them and see if the problem persists?